# My sqlite3 rebuild generates the electron-v1.4-win32-x64 and require asks for electron-v1.4-win32-ia32 . Does any have idea?

Tags: sqlite, electron, electron-builder

This are the snap of the app and the snap of the compiled node file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

We are getting wrong build because we are using the 32bit version of nodejs in 64bit arch.

You can verify the arch of your nodejs by using the process.

```
c:\> node
> process
```

Search for target_arch

[image]

If there written 32 than goto the nodejs.org and download the 64bit installer of the nodejs.

Step to follow

1. Remove the node_modules folder
2. Open command prompt (run as admin)
3. Check the node process arch type is x64 shown in image.
4. run npm install

My package.json file

```
  {
  "name": "sqlite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is the tutorial for the sqllite",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild  -f -w  sqlite3"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.5.10"
  }
}
```